# Print a DataTable to a printer

Tags: c#, .net, console

I am writing a C# .NET console app. I need to print the contents of a `DataTable` to a printer.  Most of the solutions I've found online are for ASP.NET and the others for Windows Forms based apps.  Any code scraps welcome.

Comment: when `.net-5.0` was released?

Comment: @DaveDev ouch I missed that update ;/

Comment: And after of course .net 4.5

Comment: You should post those examples as links. The fact that it's ASP.NET, WinForms or WPF has nothing to do with datatables and printing, so the interesting part of that code can probably be reused.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... I found the answer on MSDN and since I had to reformat the code I am providing a link to my [code](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Byr7oW6nd6x_OGhrX1pkdXJEb3M/edit?usp=sharing).  Basically I pasted this into a utility class for my project and added the static keyword to the PrintFile method.